# cannot generate bitcoin first block

Tags: bitcoin-core, hash, genesis-block

I have download bitcoin source and change genesis in regtest. and i try to generate 1 block by command ./bitcoin-cli -generate 1 it does not show any mining block. i try over 10 times but it is still the same result why?

```
here the result:
{
  "address": "tc1qltnl9t23yshlexxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "blocks": [
  ]
}
```

please kindly advise what happen what bitcoin source code ?

Comment: Try `generatetoaddress`: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.21.0/rpc/generating/generatetoaddress/